# VPS Ошибка 500 из-за .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте. Переношу сайт из хостинга на VPS, столкнулся с тем, что после загрузки файла .htaccess в корень, сайт начал выдавать ошибку 500.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

php_flag display_errors on 
php_flag display_startup_errors on 
php_value error_reporting 2047

Options -Indexes

#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
#</IfModule>

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^p/support/q/([0-9]+)$ inc/pages/support/q.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ inc/pages/$1/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\/]+)$ inc/pages/$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^do/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\/]+)$ php/$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)/?([a-z]+)?$ inc/pages/users/id.php?id=$1&subname=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Закомментируйте строки, а потом по одной сверху вниз снова включайте и проверяйте когда появится 500 ошибка. Потом смотрите к какому модулю относится команда все сломавшая и включайте этот модуль в конфиге апача.

Comment: благодарю. можете оставить ответ, чтобы я пометил его, как верный?